# Here Maps SDK: Configuration of marker clustering

Tags: android, maps, here-api

is there any way to configure the clustering of markers in the Here Maps Android SDK? By configuration I don't mean the color and/or the icon of the cluster markers but how many markers should be at least clustered together so I don't get many small clusters on a relatively high zoom level.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, for mSDKs is not possible to set parameters to configure the clustering e.g. like: the min/max point weight sum to form a cluster or the value of the radius within which data points are considered for clustering.

Comment: is there a way to temporarily disable clustering for a ClusterLayer?